# Why won't my JavaScript work!? It's selecting the ID but won't apply display changes

Tags: javascript, html, css

Before I get in to this, I know I should learn jQuery but I haven't got to that yet, I want to learn raw JavaScript first! Well, mostly. Can someone help me without the use of jQuery please just for understanding, thank you!:

Hi, I'm new to JavaScript, not long started learning it as you can see by the first code (which works so I'm leaving it) for the navigation.

However, my problem comes on the 2nd piece of code I'm trying something from a different angle after watching videos on event listeners etc and everything I have written makes sense, to me, I'm going through it step by step, it's selecting all the right stuff, but it's still not showing the desired result!!

When you click CSS i want it to show the div with id "cs", and same for the HTML and JavaScript ones.

I really don't know JavaScript enough to solve this myself, I can not think of anything AT ALL to help with the problem!

Somebody save me, please, my mind is going crazy and I want to go to bed!

Here is the code, and here is the JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pmj26o9p/2/

```
var htm = document.getElementById('htm');
var css = document.getElementById('css');
var js = document.getElementById('js');

htm.addEventListener("click", contentShow);
css.addEventListener("click", contentShow);
js.addEventListener("click", contentShow);

function contentShow() {
  var whichOne = this.attributes["data-id"].value;
  var switcheroo = document.getElementById(whichOne);

switcheroo.onclick = function() {

  if (switcheroo.style.display === "none") {
    switcheroo.style.display = "";
  } else {
    switcheroo.style.display = "none";
  }

}
```

EDIT: On reading through the code again I don't think it will achieve what I want even if it works. This will let me show and hide whichever I'm clicking right?

I want to show the clicked one but then hide / apply display:none to all others that aren't clicked.

Comment: The attributes collection is an Array Like Object.

Comment: I'm sorry, that means nothing to me, it's selecting the value of the attribute "data-id" fine, I've checked via console log, and the switcheroo variable is logging the right div depending on what I click, but the function won't work! :(

Comment: If you hide a clicked element, how will you be able to click it again (or is the intention to just hide them permanently once they have been clicked)? Your jsfiddle is different from the code you posted here. Try to keep that consistent. Stackoverflow also allows you to post a code snippet (much like jsfiddle) if you press CTRL+M while posting. This is preferable because the snippet can be run from within your answer.

Comment: You don't need the line `switcheroo.onclick = function()`.  Just have the enclosed if statement straight after `var switcheroo = ...` line

Comment: @Damon, I didn't know the shortcut key for that. Nice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My example below will show the chosen block and hide the others, as per your EDIT comment.

```js
var htm = document.getElementById('htm');
var css = document.getElementById('css');
var js = document.getElementById('js');

function contentShow(el) {
  var whichOne = el.attributes["data-id"].value;
  var switcheroo = document.getElementById(whichOne);

  // show selected block, hide the others
  switch (switcheroo) {
    case htm:
      htm.style.display = "block";
      css.style.display = "none";
      js.style.display = "none";
      break;
    case js:
      htm.style.display = "none";
      css.style.display = "none";
      js.style.display = "block";
      break;
    case css:
      htm.style.display = "none";
      css.style.display = "block";
      js.style.display = "none";
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<span data-id="htm" onClick="contentShow(this)" style="margin-right:10px;color:red; cursor:pointer">Click to show the HTML Block</span>
<span data-id="css" onClick="contentShow(this)" style="margin-right:10px;color:green; cursor:pointer">Click to show the CSS Block</span>
<span data-id="js" onClick="contentShow(this)" style="margin-right:10px;color:blue; cursor:pointer">Click to show the JS Block</span>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="htm">Some HTML info here</div>
<div id="css" style="display:none">Some CSS info here</div>
<div id="js" style="display:none">Some JavaScript info here</div>
```

Comment: Of course you could eliminate the `data-id` and pass the element ID into the `onClick` if you prefered - `onClick="contentShow('css')"`. You'll need to change the javascript accordingly

Comment: Holy moly this is perfect, thank you so much! 

I've come across switch statements a few times but never understood them, this is fantastic!

So much less code than the way I've done it with my navigation, awesome! 

Two different ways aswell, thank you very much :)

Comment: Just edited the code. I had left some unnecessary JS in there

Comment: Please don't camelCase HTML attributes.

Answer (score 1):

you are binding a second event handler to the `switcheroo` element, but the click event is not triggered so nothing happens.

If you want to make a toggle function on the `switcheroo` variable, you should do this instead:

```
function contentShow() {
  var whichOne = this.attributes["data-id"].value;
  var switcheroo = document.getElementById(whichOne);
  return toggleDisplay(switcheroo);
}

function toggleDisplay(elem) {
  if (elem.style.display === "none") {
    elem.style.display = "";
  } else {
    elem.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring your other bad practices, change

```
var htm = document.getElementById('htm');
var css = document.getElementById('css');
var js = document.getElementById('js');

htm.addEventListener("click", contentShow);
css.addEventListener("click", contentShow);
js.addEventListener("click", contentShow);

function contentShow() {
  var whichOne = this.attributes["data-id"].value;
  var switcheroo = document.getElementById(whichOne);

switcheroo.onclick = function() {

  if (switcheroo.style.display === "none") {
    switcheroo.style.display = "";
  } else {
    switcheroo.style.display = "none";
  }

}
```

to something more like:

```
var doc = document;
function E(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id); // you guessed it - same as document.getElementById, without typing it every time
}
var htm = E('htm'), css = E('css'), js = E('js');
contentShow = (function(){ // self-executing scopes off var showing - variable style assignment requires function definition before execution
  var showing = false;
  return function(){ // returns unexecuted function
    var ht = E('ht').style, cs = E('cs').style, jsc = E('jsc').style;
    if(showing){
      ht.display = cs.display = jsc.display = 'none'; showing = false;
    }
    else{
      ht.display = cs.display = jsc.display = 'block'; showing = true;
    }
  }
})();
htm.addEventListener('click', contentShow);
css.addEventListener('click', contentShow);
js.addEventListener('click', contentShow);
```

See updated JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pmj26o9p/5/).

If there are no other click Events on those Elements, you could even change

```
htm.addEventListener('click', contentShow);
css.addEventListener('click', contentShow);
js.addEventListener('click', contentShow);
```

to

```
htm.onclick = css.onclick = js.onclick = contentShow;
```

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/pmj26o9p/6/)

but keep in mind this technique overwrites previous Events of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

I know you're looking for a javascript solution here.and kudos to you for wanting to understand javascript before getting into jquery, but here is an out of the box solution for you.... pure HTML and CSS

```css
.info {display:none;}
.info:target{display:block;}
```

```html
<a href="#htm" style="margin-right:10px;color:red;">Click to show the HTML Block</a>
<a href="#css" style="margin-right:10px;color:green;">Click to show the CSS Block</a>
<a href="#js"  style="margin-right:10px;color:blue;">Click to show the JS Block</a>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="htm" class="info">Some HTML info here</div>
<div id="css" class="info">Some CSS info here</div>
<div id="js"  class="info">Some JavaScript info here</div>
```

What I've done here is, leverage internal page id links and the `:target` selector. In my mind, this is more semantic and can also still be extended by scripting while still maintaining semantics. This option also gives your uses the option of bookmarking selections etc.

**CSS OPTION 2**

This option achieves the initial display. It is not as clean and uses absolute positioning and z-indexes. Alos note that is uses a background color to conceal the initial option.

```css
.info {position:relative;}
.info > div {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background-color:#FFF;
  z-index:10;
  display: none;
}

#htm
{
  display:block;
  z-index:1;
}

.info > div:target {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#htm" style="margin-right:10px;color:red;">Click to show the HTML Block</a>
<a href="#css" style="margin-right:10px;color:green;">Click to show the CSS Block</a>
<a href="#js" style="margin-right:10px;color:blue;">Click to show the JS Block</a>
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="info">
  <div id="htm">Some HTML info here</div>
  <div id="css">Some CSS info here</div>
  <div id="js">Some JavaScript info here</div>
</div>
```

On a side note you should consider adding/removing css classes using javascript instead of the display property directly. This will enable the use of CSS transitions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a variation of @K Scandrett answer which add some scalability/flexibility

```js
var navElements = document.getElementsByClassName("nav");

//Add Event Listeners
for(var i = 0; i < navElements.length; i ++)
{
    navElements[i].addEventListener('click', contentShow, false);    
}

function contentShow(el) {
  var whichOne = el.target.attributes["data-id"].value;
  var target = document.getElementById(whichOne);

  for(var i = 0; i < navElements.length; i ++)
  {
    var content = document.getElementById(navElements[i].attributes["data-id"].value)
    content.style.display = content === target ? "block" : "none";      
  }
}
```

```html
<span data-id="htm" style="margin-right:10px;color:red; cursor:pointer" class="nav">Click to show the HTML Block</span>
<span data-id="css"  style="margin-right:10px;color:green; cursor:pointer" class="nav">Click to show the CSS Block</span>
<span data-id="js"  style="margin-right:10px;color:blue; cursor:pointer" class="nav">Click to show the JS Block</span>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="htm">Some HTML info here</div>
<div id="css" style="display:none">Some CSS info here</div>
<div id="js" style="display:none">Some JavaScript info here</div>
```